# Automatically mounting Truecrypt volumes at user login time

Tags: ubuntu, mount, shell-script, truecrypt, upstart

I need to mount a Truecrypt volume automatically at user login time. This volume is specific for each user.

I'm not sure how to proceed since I'm not extremely familiar with Linux and the various startup scripts involved.

All Truecrypt volumes are located on my network. I already have the relevant /etc/fstab entry to mount the network drive properly.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (in GNOME classic session mode, if this matters, I did hear it does). Truecrypt needs root privileges when mounting a volume. **My users have no root privilege, that's an additional difficulty I have.**

Thank you.

Comment: How should the user be prompted for the password / keyfile?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. He should not. The mount operation should be completely transparent for the user.

Comment: Nobody for this question? Does anybody know if I can configure an upstart script at user login time, with root privileges when executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add

```
truecrypt /home/user/myEncryptedFile.tc /home/user/myEncryptedFileFolder <<EOF
password
EOF
```

to the file *.profile* in the user's home-directory.
Anything in .profile while be executed everytime the user logs in.

Source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TrueCrypt#Automatic_mount_on_login

Comment: Seems like /etc/.profile is a good place, as it is executed with root privileges, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This would defeat the purpose of Truecrypt unless you are using whole disk encryption. If you do it this way, all the user would have to do is crack the account's password to gain access to the encrypted files. That being said, hopefully the other answer will answer your question.

Comment: Agreed - doing this, somebody knowing the Linux password of a particular account would be able to read the startup script in which the password is stored, in other words the volume would in effect be protected only with the Linux login password, not with AES. I could live with that.
Now that I think about it the main weakness with my original suggestion is the -p option on the truecrypt commandline which makes the password visible to ps. That IS very bad, I admit.

Comment: @MartinFrank Keep in mind that Linux passwords are a whole lot easier to crack than TrueCrypt.