# Auomatically mounting TrueCrypt protected volumes

Tags: windows-7, truecrypt, opensuse-12.2

I use both Windows 7 and openSUSE 12.2.

The system partitions are both secured at boot time (BitLocker and LVM).

I want to share data between OSes, but the data must be encrypted too.

I ran into TrueCrypt. Seems working very good. One problem: it will ask me for password at every boot. Since boot partitions are secured I'm comfortable in storing the password "plaintext" on an encrypted drive.

### Linux part of the question

I found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/513640/automatically-mounting-truecrypt-volumes-at-user-login-time) partially answering the Linux part of the question. In fact, implementing the `mount.truecrypt` [script](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TrueCrypt#Automatic_mount_on_login) always prompts me for encryption password, which is what I don't want

Then, is it possible to specify mount options in `fstab` (that is, again, encrypted on system drive) to automatically provide password?

An alternate way of specifying the password **is** hard coding it in `mount.truecrypt` script with `-p` option, but has the disadvantage of requiring all drives using the same password

### Windows part of the question

What about auto-mounting volumes in Windows at boot/login time without typing the password and without being asked for UAC?

Comment: You can mount automatically volumes under Windows if the boot password is the same as the volume password. All you need to do is to setup volumes as favorite in the TrueCrypt GUI.

Comment: I'm sorry. I use BitLocker to secure Windows boot, not TrueCrypt. So TC password can't be the same as the boot "password" (because I use USB token)

Comment: Create a .bat file containing truecrypt command line to pass the password and mount the selected volumes automatically. Here you can find all the necessary parameters: http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=command-line-usage . Place the bat file in the startup folder.

Comment: @mnmnc I updated my question not because I don't believe your suggestion, but I because haven't tried it *yet*. Please don't mind if I leave the Windows part open